# How to copy a folder which is contain date formate(DDMMYYYY) as folder name

Tags: batch-file

How to copy a folder which is contain date formate(DDMMYYYY) as folder name and folder name will differ from month to month. How can I create batch file for this.

Comment: You may not need grep - but you haven't supplied enough details about the task.  Is it the current month you are copying?  Is there only one folder inside the subdirectory?  Give examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "startfolder=."
set "targetfolder=C:\destination"
cd /d "%startfolder%"
for /f "delims=" %%a ('dir /ad /b ^|grep -E "(([12][0-9]|0[1-9])02|(30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(0[469]|11)|(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])(0[13578]|1[02]))[0-9]{4}"') do (
    md "%targetfolder%\%%~nxa"
    copy "%%~a" "%targetfolder%\%%~nxa"
)
```

`findstr` doesn't have enough Regex capabilities, you need [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).